# Injecting translator object to translate my message or translate it externally? Which one is the proper OO way?

Tags: php, oop

I have a general question regarding proper OO code.
I have two classes: **MyClass** and **MyMessage** and i want to translate the message key **MyMessage::message**.

Now i have two options to choose from:

In the first example a translator object is injected and the message has the responsibility to translate my message.

- One possible pro i can imagine is that MyMessage and possible
  subclasses are able to return a formatted string they want!
- One contra is, that both classes have to deal with a dependency like
  **Translator**

In the second example **MyMessage** is just a dumb object which holds data and the client is responsible to translate it.

- Pro: Translator dependency is only used in MyClass.
- Contra: MyMessage is not able to translate the string it possible wants.

My question is: Which one is the better one?

```
class MyMessage
{    
    private $message; 
    private $args;

    public function getMessage(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        return $translator->trans($this->message, $this->args);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $myMessage = new MyMessage();
        ...
        $translatedMessage = $myMessage->getMessage($translator);
    }

}
```

..or this:

```
class MyMessage
{    
    private $message; 
    private $args;

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function getArguments()
    {
        return $this->args;
    }

}

class MyClient
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $myMessage = new MyMessage();
        ...
        $translatedMessage = $translator->trans(
             $myMessage->getMessage($translator), 
             $myMessage->getArgs($translator)
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: IMHO, the more correct OOP approach would be to create a third class that takes obejcts that implement an interface, ensuring a `getMessage` method being present, and have that class take care of the output (translation, representation). In MVC terms, the Message is a data model, the Client is a controller/service class which means the translator is a view component. All three have distinct responsibilities, hence all three should be separate classes that exist independently

Answer (score 1):

I would chose the first approach, where the translation service / translator object is injected. This will allow you to separate the message retrieval logic from the translation logic. If at some point you want to use a different message storing mechanism - move between XML, SQL or whatever - or change your translation logic (TMX / SQL / whatever) you can change one without affecting the other. Also, you can inject a mock translator for unit testing purposes.

Dependency injection is not an issue and it will save you a lot of headaches.